# How to implement a division function without the operator, loop or recursion?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I need to convert this function using the functional programming paradigm but I don't know how, I can use reducer or map creating an array but I don't know how to implement it,  i can't use divide operator, loop or recursion;

```js
function divide(dividend, divisor) {
  var result = 0;
  while (dividend >= divisor) {
    dividend -= divisor;
    result++;
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(divide(100, 2));
```

Comment: `reduce` and `map` can only be used on Arrays, So In this case there is no need of reduce or map. You can directly get resut using `return Math.floor(dividend / divisor);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to do it declaratively is with a recursive function....

```js
const divide = (t, b, depth = 0) => t < b ? depth : divide(t-b, b, depth+1);

console.log(`150 / 3 = ${divide(150, 3)}`);
console.log(`24 / 3 = ${divide(24, 3)}`);
console.log(`4 / 3 = ${divide(4, 3)}`);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit puzzled by the requirements. My understanding is that loops or recursion aren't prohibited in functional programming. Assuming this is an exercise (it has to be) then here's another way to look at it:

To solve `a / b` you can count how many `b` you can fit in `a`. So for example:

```
10 / 2 -> [2, 2, 2, 2, 2] -> 5
```

or:

```
            +2 +2 +2 +2 (map)
10 / 2 -> [2, 4, 6, 8, 10] -> 5
           ^           ^^
          (x)         (pred)
```

So we can unfold the divisor into a list of sums of itself:

```js
const unfold = (pred, map, x) => {
  const ys = [];
  for (let y = x; pred(y); y = map(y)) ys.push(y);
  return ys;
}

unfold(x => x <= 10, x => x + 2, 2);
//=> [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

Now we can implement `divide` with `unfold` and return the length of the list:

```js
const divide = (a, b) =>
  unfold(x => x <= a, x => x + b, b)
    .length;

divide(10, 2);
//=> 5
```

Comment: The least "functional" thing in this answer is the for-loop since it produces a side-effect on `ys`.  It's kind of a fad lately to force the code this way. Doing so often produces code only its author likes to read, and it's often wasteful at run time. (e.g. my answer absurdly builds x/y stack frames, yours builds an array that's x/y long).

Comment: We could make this (clever but tortured) approach purely function by allocating an array of length `a`, prefilled with `b`, then find the index where the accumulated sum > `a`.  Nutty, but this would qualify:  `(new Array(a).fill(b)).findIndex(el => (sum+=el) > a)` (preceded by let sum=0;)

Answer (score 0):

My Final solution is this:

```
const adition = (a, b) => a + b;

const subtraction = (a, b) => a - b;

const multiplication = (a, b) => {
    return b >= 0 ? [...Array(b)].reduce((acc) => adition(acc, a), 0) : [...Array(a)].reduce((acc) => adition(acc, b), 0);
};

const division = (a, b) => {
    return a === 0 || b === 0 ? 'Error' : b > 1 ? [...Array(a).keys()].reduce((acc, num) => multiplication(num, b) <= a ? adition(acc, 1) : acc, -1) : a;
};
```